# Does Google Analytics subdomain tracking need to be set up on every subdomain simultaneously?

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

I'm cleaning up the Google Analytics tracking for a complex corporate website.

The website is spread across a bunch of subdomains (`www.example.com` for the main content, `dev.example.com` for developer information, `pages.example.com` for legacy content, and so on) and I've found that each subdomain uses its own tracking cookie, so Analytics treats them all as separate sites (when tracking referrals, for example) even though the data all feeds into the same web property.

[As Google recommends](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#domainSubDomains), I'm going to fix this by adding `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']);` to the tracking code on each subdomain, so that they all use the same tracking cookie. However, the site is very complex and several different groups maintain their own subdomains, so it's going to be difficult to coordinate the switchover.

In particular, [this comment](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/analytics/uMk0ktfO-YI/_X7COJx00dAJ) gives me pause:

> Yes you have to use `setDomainName(".mydomain.com")` on all `www` pages as well. Otherwise cookies might get overwritten everytime you change subdomains and data loss will occur.

So, given that:

- the bare domain (`example.com`) just redirects to the `www` subdomain, and
- some of the subdomains currently have the `_setDomainName` method explicitly set to `'none'`, but some don't have it set at all,

do we risk any data corruption if we stagger the tracking code update across the subdomains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This relates to how cookies are shared across sub-domains. A cookie set on your main site with the domain `www.example.com` can't be accessed by `pages.example.com`, however a cookie set with the domain `example.com` can be accessed by both. It doesn't matter that `example.com` just redirects to your main site, your main site can still use `example.com` as the domain with cookies that it sets (as `www.example.com` is a subdomain of `example.com`). Sounds more complicated than it is!

So, I'd suggest:

- Modify the tracking code on your main domain first (to add the `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']);`
- Then modify your sub-domains as and when you can

If you don't do this, then someone who arrives at `www.example.com` and then clicked on  a link to `pages.example.com` would be registered as two visitors, because Google Analytics wouldn't be able to track that they're the same person. So that's what the comment means by "data corruption".

Comment: Thank you! I still didn't quite understand how Analytics chose which domain to set its cookies on, so I cleared the site's cookies in my browser and watched them repopulate as I visited various subdomains. Apparently, all the subdomains except `www`, whether  `_setDomainName` is explicitly set to `none` or left as the default, set their cookies on their full domain (for example, `.pages.example.com` or `.dev.example.com`). Only `www` set its cookies on `.example.com`, which supports what you say about its cookies being the only ones at risk of being overwritten.

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, do you know how Google Analytics knows that `www` is the "main" subdomain and should set its cookies on the domain? Is it because `www.example.com` is set as the web property's default URL in Analytics, or is it just a fundamental assumption of the web?